# Get error when generate some barcodes using milon and laravel with if conditional

Tags: ajax, laravel, barcode

I want to ask for solution when generating barcode using if conditional based on number lenght.

1. If I generate barcode with code like this below, the result absolutely no problem.

   ```
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    @foreach ($produks as $item)

        @if ($i <= 5)
            <div class="box">
                <div class="title">{{ $item['nama'] }}</div>

                {{ DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML($item['sku'], 'EAN13') }}

                <div class="sku">{{ $item['sku'] }}</div>
            </div>
            <?php $i++; ?>
        @else
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
            <?php $i = 1; ?>
        @endif


    @endforeach
   ```
2. But if I use "if conditional" with strlen in there, I've got error. I want to print a barcode based on the length of the number

   ```
    @foreach ($produks as $item)
        @if ($i <= 5)
            <div class="box">
                <div class="title">{{ $item['nama'] }}</div>

                @if (strlen($item['sku']) == 12)
                    {{ DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML($item['sku'], 'UPCA') }}
                @else
                    {{ DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML($item['sku'], 'EAN13') }}
                @endif

                <div class="sku">{{ $item['sku'] }}</div>
            </div>
            <?php $i++; ?>
        @else
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
            <?php $i = 1; ?>
        @endif
    @endforeach
   ```
3. This my ajax post

   ```
    $('#barcode').click(function() {
                var rows_selected = $('#dt-produk').DataTable().column(12).checkboxes.selected();
                var id = [];
                $.each(rows_selected, function(index, rowId) {
                    id.push(rowId);
                });

                var datax = JSON.stringify(id);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('cetakBarcode.produk') }}",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        id: datax
                    },
                    xhrFields: {
                        responseType: 'blob'
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        var blob = new Blob([response]);
                        var link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        link.download = "barcode-produk.pdf";
                        link.click();
                    },
                    error: function(blob) {
                        console.log(blob);
                    }
                })

            });
   ```
4. This is the controller

   ```
     function cetakBarcode(Request $req)
        {
            $ids = json_decode(stripslashes($req->id));
            $datax = [];
            foreach ($ids as $id) {
                $produk = DB::table('produks')->where('id', $id)->first();
                $datax[] = [
                    'nama' => $produk->nama,
                    'harga_jual' => $produk->harga_jual,
                    'sku' => $produk->sku
                ];
            }
            $datax = [
                'title' => 'Label Produk',
                'date' => date('m/d/Y'),
                'produks' => $datax
            ];

            $pdf = PDF::loadView('pages.master.produk.barcode', $datax);
            $path = public_path('file/pdf');
            $fileName =  'barcode-produk.' . 'pdf';
            $pdf->save($path . '/' . $fileName);

            $pdf = public_path('file/pdf/' . $fileName);

            return response()->download($pdf);
        }
   ```

The error **is 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Comment: when you ask a question on stack overflow please provide code in the question, Not on another service and not an image. the reason for this is if someone were to search for the same question and the third party service no longer exists or has removed your image.

Comment: Ok thank you, sir

Answer (score 0):

So I've just ran a few tests using this library, It throws some exceptions if the values are not in the correct format, Since you are running this inside a blade view, You will have to use the `@php`e.g.

```
 @php
    try {
        if (strlen($item['sku']) == 12) {
            echo DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML($item['sku'], 'UPCA');
        } else {
            echo DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML($item['sku'], 'EAN13');
        }
    } catch (\Milon\Barcode\WrongCheckDigitException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
@endphp
```

Comment: Thanks in advance for helping, sir. It seems to be working but there are some barcodes that are not showing up.
the error is print like this "Expected 2 get 1", "Expected 3 get 1" etc.

Comment: Yeah, this is because you are proving the sku in the wrong format for UPCA. thats why we have a try catch in there.